# Rails - rake build error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rakefile

I'm setting up my dev environment for a new project, where the instructions use rake (something I've never used).

I've just imported some JSON data into mongodb with

```
mongoimport --db mydevenvironment --port 27017 --collection places --file mydir/tmp/places.json
```

The next command is to use rake to build, as follows:

```
rake build:devenvironment_from_files[,,,,1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8/9/10/11/12/13/14/15/16/17/18/19,27017] --trace
```

I've found very little documentation anywhere online for the rake build command.  How does it work exactly, and what do the array of numbers signify? Are these file locations?

The error I get is:

```
zsh: no matches found: build:devenvironment_from_files[,,,,1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8/9/10/11/12/13/14/15/16/17/18/19,27017]
```

But I've no idea where to start diagnosing this.

Comment: http://mikeballou.com/blog/2011/07/18/zsh-and-rake-parameters/ - may be a solution which I'm looking into...

Comment: You may need to escape the `[` char.

Comment: Or the `noglob` which you found, but then you need to explicitly allow globbing when you need it.

Comment: Basic OS stuff; odds are `noglob` won't affect you for running `rake` anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. Add alias rake='noglob rake' in your .zshrc.

Solution :- http://mikeballou.com/blog/2011/07/18/zsh-and-rake-parameters/